# Sqlite3 giving error while running the program

Tags: go, go-fiber

I was following along with a tutorial and had to use SQLite since it was beginner-friendly after everything while running the command `go run main.go` I'm getting an error telling

```
# github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
cc1.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
```

not sure if this is caused by SQLite or something, so some help would be appreciated,also I'll put the link below of the code since IDK where it is causing the problem
https://github.com/bavan172/Golang-Fiber_crm-basic

Comment: try this https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29679

Answer (score 0):

you can give a try to a CGo-free port of sqlite: https://pkg.go.dev/modernc.org/sqlite

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).